# How to print receipt with Thermal Printer using html / javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, printing

How to use thermal print using javascript.

I have tried with `HTML/JavaScript` print code but it doesn't load properly view like that font-size, font-style.

Please suggest me how can I implement?

Comment: Sounds more like a hardware or a driver issue

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit [help] to see what and [ask] - HINT: Post effort and CODE. There is nothing in your question that can help us help you